# Retrieve different data from same table in two columns

Tags: sql

Hey I would like to display data through a query.

This data is gotten from two tables `data-pool` and `sales-representative`. They have a one to many relationship. The fields in data_pool are `follows id, date , sales-rep-1, sales-rep-2`. The field in sales-representatives are `id, sales-rep-name`.

These two tables have two similar one to many relationship by this I mean the id field of sales-representatives can appear in data-pool in both the sales-rep-1 and sales-rep-2 field. in one row the fields will always have different id's.

How can I run a query to retrieve both sales-rep-name for a particular date?

Comment: please update your question with; the database you are using, table structures and example data, the output required and most importantly what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this query:

```
select dp.id, dp.date , dp.sales-rep-1, sr1.sales-rep-name, dp.sales-rep-2, 
      sr2.sales-rep-name  
from data-pool as dp, sales-representatives as sr1, 
      sales-representatives as sr2 
where dp.sales-rep-1=sr1.id and dp.sales-rep-2=sr2.id
```